# Compression not working in asp.net + angular + unity application

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-game-engine, response-headers, brotli

so I am building an asp.net+angular app in which I am placing a webgl unity build. I am trying to add brotli compression but for some reason, in the response headers, I am not shown the content-encoding property and I am still getting the following "tip":
[image]

This is what my response headers look like:
[image]
As you can see, there is no "content-encoding"

This is my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO.Compression;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
// CONFIG START

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => config.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"); // ovo je kriticno, path


//builder.Services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal);
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.MimeTypes = new[] {
        "application/octet-stream",
        "application/vnd.unity"
    };
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
});


// CONFIG END
var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()){
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.UseStaticFiles();
//var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
//provider.Mappings.Remove(".unityweb");
//provider.Mappings.Add(".unityweb", "application/octet-stream");
//app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{
//   ContentTypeProvider = provider
//});


app.UseRouting();

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);


app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an ordering issue. You need to put:

app.UseResponseCompression();

Before:

app.UseStaticFiles();